# How to generate with a recursive function all the permuted sets of an array with the first element of all the permuted sets fixed

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, set, permutation

Let's considerer the following array A=[1,2,3,4].
I would like to generate a function that is recursive and that returns a new array of arrays B, and B=[[1,2,3,4,],[1,3,2,4],[1,4,2,3],[1,3,4,2],[1,2,4,3],[1,4,3,2]].
I have made the following code:

```
arr=[1,2,3,4]
arr_new=[arr[0]]
subsets_array=[]
j=0
m=1
def perm(arr,j,m):
    global arr_new
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        if i!=j:
            arr_new=arr_new+[arr[i]]
            
            print(arr_new)
        if len(arr_new)==m+1:
            arr_new.pop(j+1)
    perm(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
    #return subsets_array
    #
perm(arr,0,1)
```

The problem with this code is the following:
it produces repetitive arrays like [1,2,3,4] appears more than one time. And also, perm doesn't return the array of arrays.

I have tried to fix the last code with the following fixs:

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
arr_new=[arr[0]]
subsets_array=[]
j=0
m=1
def perm(arr,j,m):
    global arr_new
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        if i!=j:
            for x in range(0,len(arr_new)):
                if arr_new[x]!=arr[i]:
                    arr_new=arr_new+[arr[i]]
            #print(arr_new)
                    subsets_array.append(arr_new)   
        if len(arr_new)==m+1:
            arr_new.pop(j+1)
    perm(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
    return subsets_array
    #
perm(arr,0,1)
```

But, the function is not returning me the array of arrays as I wanted and I cannot understand why.

Comment: why do you need recursive function for this? It can be done in one line solution

Comment: I wanted to practice Recursive functions

Comment: The very first list you add to `subsets_array` is already not what you say you want (it only has two elements). It is quite easy to understand why ... step through the code with a debugger and you'll see. I wonder why you wrote these nested loops... in the end you have an `x` and don't use it in the subarray. First do this on a piece of paper to make sure you have an algorithm that works before coding it.

Comment: BTW, you never seem to mark an answer as accepted. Not really motivating.

Comment: @trincot, I didn't know that I have to do it. I will

Answer (score 1):

```
def perm(arr,i,j):

    def iters(_arr,l=[]):
        if len(l) == n:
            yield (l)
        else:
            for i in range(len(_arr)):
                narr = _arr.copy()
                yield from iters(narr,l=l+[narr.pop(i)])
    n = j-i
    for v in iters(arr[i:j]):

        print(arr[:i] + v + arr[j:])


perm([1,2,3,4],1,4)
```

Comment: thanks, but how do you fix a[0] in the first position? (or any other a[i] with 1<i<len(arr)-1)

Comment: @LucianoMuratore, did you run the code? It fixes the first index. What you put in parentheses is not in your question. The title of your question clearly says you want to fix the **first** value.

Comment: @trincot, I also mentioned that I wanted the function to return an array of arrays. Please, take a look at the problem before answering.

Comment: Sure, but that is another topic. I am reacting to your first comment here. NB: I didn't answer.

Answer (score 1):

By adding a `skip` parameter to a simple recursive permutation function will allow you to keep it simple.  You only need to add the skipped prefix in the first iteration and use a zero-skip value when drilling down:

A simple recursive permutation function could look like this:

```
def permute(A):
    if not A: yield []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for p in permute(A[:i]+A[i+1:]):
            yield [A[i],*p]
```

With the added parameter, it can skip the first item (or more):

```
def permute(A,skip=1):
    if not A: yield []
    for i in range(skip,len(A)):
        for p in permute(A[skip:i]+A[i+1:],0):
            yield A[:skip] + [A[i],*p]
```

output:

```
print(*permute([1,2,3,4]),sep="\n")

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
```